# Get latest message in conversation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have two Mongoose collections - `conversation` and `message` - and I want to display a list of the conversations a particular user is in, sorted by the most recent message, with a preview of that message below the name of the conversation

After I've gotten the user's conversations, how can I select ONLY the latest message from each conversation, and attach those messages to their corresponding conversations? (Given the schema looks something like this):

```
var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    participants: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    }
});

var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    conversation: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Conversation', required: true},
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true}
});
```

I'm getting the message that I should probably be using Mongo's "Aggregation" framework, but I've never used that before so I'd like some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The aggregation framework indeed will be your pal for this task. With the aggregation, it works by distilling collections down to essential information, using a multi-stage pipeline of filters, groupers, sorters, transformations and other operators. The distilled set of results is produced far more efficiently than other techniques.

For your above use case, the aggregation consists of a series of special operators applied to a collection called a pipeline:

```
[
    { "$match": { /* options */ } },
    { "$lookup": { /* options */ } },  
    { "$group": { /* options */ } }
]
```

When executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So Mongo executes the previous pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $match | $lookup | $group => result
```

Now, applying the above to your task, you need a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step as your first stage in the aggregation as it allows you to filter the document stream with only matching documents passing unmodified into the next pipeline stage. So if you run the aggregation on the `Conversation` model with just the
**[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** query object, you will get documents that a particular user is in:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants": userId } }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

You can pipe another operator, in this case you need the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator which performs a left outer join to the `messages` collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants": userId } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "messages",
            "localfield": "_id",
            "foreignField": "conversation",
            "as": "messages"
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

This will output to console the fields from the `conversation` document as well as a new array field called "messages" whose elements are the matching documents from the "joined" `messages` collection. The **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** stage passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.

Now that you've got the user's `conversations` together with the `messages`, how do you then select `ONLY` the latest message from each conversation?

This can be achieved through the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator, but before applying the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator on the documents from the previous pipeline,
you need to flatten the `messages` array in order to get the latest document and the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator will deconstruct the array elements for you.

When the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator is applied on an array field, it will generate a new record for each and every element of the list on which **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** is applied:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants": userId } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "messages",
            "localfield": "_id",
            "foreignField": "conversation",
            "as": "messages"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$messages" }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

Assuming your `MessageSchema` has a timestamp field (say `createdAt`) that denotes the datetime the message was sent, you can re-order your documents by that field in descending order, ready for processing to the next pipeline. The **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator is perfect for such:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants": userId } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "messages",
            "localfield": "_id",
            "foreignField": "conversation",
            "as": "messages"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$sort": { "messages.createdAt": -1 } }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

Having denormalised documents, you can then group the data to process them. The group pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions (called [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators)). The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. MongoDB identifies the grouping expression with the `_id` field only and in this case group the documents by the `_id` field:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants": userId } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "messages",
            "localfield": "_id",
            "foreignField": "conversation",
            "as": "messages"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$sort": { "messages.createdAt": -1 } }
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "participants": { "$first": "$participants" },
            "latestMessage": { "$first": "$message" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

In the above, we are interested in the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** group accumulator operator as it returns a value from the first document for each group. Because the previous pipeline operator sorts the documents in a descending order, the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** will give you the `LATEST` message.

So, running the above last aggregation operation will give you the desired result. This assumes the `MessageSchema` has a timestamp which is essential in determining the latest message, otherwise it will only work up to the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** step.